# Learn the meaning of some Terms in Srivaishnava Sampradaya

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

I've been conversing with a few people in the Sri Vaishnaava Sampradaya. Often they use the below terms. I'd like to understand the meaning of it and whether they are tamil or sanskrit words.

1. Perumal "Elai" . Meaning of the word "Elai"? When and where and in what context it should be used?
2. "Ezhundhuruliar"
3. "Saatrumarai"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elai is colloquial for ezhundhu-aruLi. Literal meaning is 'get up an bless' but is used for 'arrival'.

Saatrumurai is the concluding portion of worship to the Lord which involves chanting vedas and other texts including divya prabandham.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, Could you please throw some light on when Saatrumurai is performed and where? Like, is it performed at temples or at homes? At what time?

Comment: It can be performed anywhere worship is performed. It is just the concluding portion of worship. If you worship as per protocol, it will conclude with Satrumurai where one recites  last 2 verses of Tiruppavai, Pallandu minimum after which theertha prasadam is distributed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!